# C#: What is the mistake in this code?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication20
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {     

string[] formats ={
            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt",
            "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss",
            "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
            "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt",
            "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss",
            "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
            "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "MM/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt",
            "MM/d/yyyy H:mm:ss", 
            "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",   
            "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
            "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt", 
            "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss"     
          };
        string date1 = "11/08/2008 4:00:49";

        DateTime result;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, formats,
                          new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                          DateTimeStyles.None,
                          out result))
        {
            DateTime startTime = result;
        }

        Console.Write(startTime);

   }
    }
}
```

please explain me .. why always that if statement returns false ..
 Thanx for help and support, [Rik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5409/rik),[Phillip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41410/phillip-ngan),[Joel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn) and [Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5380/kent-boogaart) and everyone else ..

Comment: How does this code even compile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should declare (and initialize)

```
DateTime startTime
```

Outside the IF statement, or

```
Console.WriteLine(startTime)
```

Inside the IF statement.

You can try to change the value of the DateTimeStyles parameter to either AssumeLocal or AssumeUniversal (depending on your needs) to allow for the lack of a time-zone specification.

Comment: @Brian: DateTime is a struct an therefore cannot be null. It can however, be uninitialized which is probably not a good thing either.

Comment: @Aravind: try using another enum value for DateTimeStyles.

Comment: I'm guessing either AssumeLocal or AssumeUniversal, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 19):

You've declared startTime within the scope of a different block from which you're printing it out. Try changing to:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, formats,
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out result))
{
    DateTime startTime = result;
    Console.Write(startTime);
}
```

Comment: @Aravind: as per my answer, you can move the usage into the same scope as the declaration. Another option is to widen the scope of the declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Kent Boggart nailed your compiler error, but I noticed one other problem with your formats.  You're mixing combinations of different month, day, hour, and am/pm formats, but you only use uppercase 'H' for your hour formats.  An uppercase 'H' means use 24 hour time, while an lowercase 'h' means use 12 hour time.  So you should probably only have the uppercase 'H' on samples where you don't have a 'tt' option, like this:

```
string[] formats ={
        "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
        ....
};
```

Comment: oh really? .. I had similar kind of doubt ..but wasn't clarified with .. thanQ very much .. (sorry but there can be only ONE best answer ..) so +1 :) :P

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring and init'n startTime inside of your if. Try

```
        DateTime result;
        DateTime startTime = new DateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, formats,
                          new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                          DateTimeStyles.None,
                          out result))
        {
            startTime = result;
        }

        Console.Write(startTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code snippet that works - no compiler error, and the 'if' statement succeeds. Note, that you need to put a Console.ReadKey() at the end of the file in order to keep the cmd window from disappearing too quickly.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace so1888431_timestringparse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] formats ={
            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt",
            "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss",
            "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
            "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt",
            "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss",
            "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
            "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "MM/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt",
            "MM/d/yyyy H:mm:ss", 
            "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",   
            "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
            "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt", 
            "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss"     
          };
            string date1 = "11/08/2008 4:00:49";

            DateTime result;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, formats,
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                              DateTimeStyles.None,
                              out result))
            {
                DateTime startTime = result;
                Console.Write(startTime);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

startTime is only defined in the scope of that if statement
move the Console.write into the if statement, or declare the variable above it

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the compiling error is because `startTime` goes out of scope.

The way to fix your problem properly though is to print `result` instead inside the if.

Answer (score 1):

`startTime` is only declared when the result of your `if` statement is true.

The `Console.Write(startTime)` is outside of this `if` and therefore if the `if` doesn't return true, `startTime` wont exist.